# Visualisation Software red/green

Tags: open-source, web-browser, security, visual-design

I'm looking for a display to monitor a few machines I have set up to create a sort of capture the flagged network for a few of my friends to practice and have some fun on

[image: Sans Example]

I'm hoping to get something looking like the sans example I have included in this post, probably not as advanced obviously as were only using 6 machines so an agent-based solution would be fine.

looking for something like a grid that can be viewed from 1 machine or hosted on a VM and viewed from a browser.

Has anyone seen anything or know anything that I may be able to implement?

Comment: What is your input, what data do you want to visualize? Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

You could almost certainly produce your display with [python](http://python.org), [ipython](http://ipython.org) notebooks, *(Jupyter)*, and [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/), your notebook can poll the data from any suitable locations and could be viewed either via nbviewer as a static page or as a dynamic page.

A nice example of the sort of thing that you can do is the [Periodic Table example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/periodic.html).